# get all row from database using StringRequest android

Tags: php, android, database

i would like to get all the row's in my database to my app , i user the following but i get only one row

in my activity

```
private void registerUser(final String brnachID) {
        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String tag_string_req = "req_register";

        pDialog.setMessage("Registering ...");
        showDialog();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
                AppConfig.URL_REGISTERLOGINFB, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
                hideDialog();

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                    if (!error) {

                     //this code work fine for getting one row 
                     // but i want to get all the rows in the database ,put it on spinner or String[] 

                        String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                        JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                        String brnachid= user.getString("Branchid");
                        String brnachname= user.getString("Branchname");




                    } else {

                        // Error occurred in registration. Get the error
                        // message
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting params to register url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("BranchID", brnachID);


                return params;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }
```

my php file

```
<?php



require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

// json response array
$response = array("error" => FALSE);

if (isset($_POST['BranchID'])) {

    // receiving the post params
    $BranchID = $_POST['BranchID'];


    // get the user by email and password
    $user = $db->getBranch($BranchID);

    if ($user != false) {
        // use is found
        $response["error"] = FALSE;
        $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
        $response["user"]["Branchid"] = $user["Branchid"];
        $response["user"]["Branchname"] = $user["Branchname"];
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // user is not found with the credentials
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Something went wrong. Please try again!";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required post params is missing
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "erorr";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

my DB_Functions.php > getBranch Code

```
public function getBranch($BranchID) {

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM branch WHERE branchid = ?");

        $stmt->bind_param("s", $BranchID);

        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
            $stmt->close();


                return $user;

        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
?>
```

i would like to use the StringRequest i think the only thing i need to change is where i mention in the activity code by adding for loop or try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your query from

```
"SELECT * FROM branch WHERE branchid = ?"
```

to

```
"SELECT * FROM branch WHERE branchid LIKE '%?%'"
```

Then loop through the results

Comment: if u change the code in the php file properly, u'll get a JsonArray as a result instead of the JsonObject. So in the onResponse, you have to iterate through the JsonArray..

Comment: can you show me how to code that part in ans for the android and php , coz that part is my problem ,